# Node.JS Can't select value from array

Tags: node.js

I'm currently trying to get all values from
`pricePerUnit`

but for some reason it can't seem to find it, error:
`Cannot read property 'pricePerUnit' of undefined`

This was the layout from `newJson.products[i].product_id` / `sell_summary[0]` / `buy_summary[0]`

Layout:

```
  'ENCHANTED_RAW_SALMON',
  { amount: 4101, pricePerUnit: 1571, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 32, pricePerUnit: 1601.4, orders: 1 },
  'ENCHANTED_GLISTERING_MELON',
  { amount: 160, pricePerUnit: 12001.4, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 8, pricePerUnit: 15578.5, orders: 2 },
  'PRISMARINE_SHARD',
  { amount: 4007, pricePerUnit: 1.5, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 10500, pricePerUnit: 3.8, orders: 3 },
  'ENCHANTED_EMERALD',
  { amount: 64, pricePerUnit: 972, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 1195, pricePerUnit: 1013.5, orders: 1 },
```

Code:

```js
    for (i in newJson.products) {

        var productName = newJson.products[i].product_id
        var sellSummary = newJson.products[i].sell_summary[0].pricePerUnit
        var buySummary  = newJson.products[i].buy_summary[0].pricePerUnit
        var mathSummary = buySummary-sellSummary

        array.push(
            productName,
            sellSummary,
            buySummary
        );
      
    }

    console.log(array);
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong but I would appreciate some help :).

//EDIT

Okay so, I was getting a json request which looks like this:

```
{

    "success": true,
    "lastUpdated": 1632242967119,
    "products": {
        "BROWN_MUSHROOM": {
            "product_id": "BROWN_MUSHROOM",
            "sell_summary": [
                {
                    "amount": 7857,
                    "pricePerUnit": 11.4,
                    "orders": 1
                },
                {
                    "amount": 14903,
                    "pricePerUnit": 11.3,
                    "orders": 1
                },
                {
                    "amount": 59218,
                    "pricePerUnit": 11.1,
                    "orders": 1
                }
            ],
            "buy_summary": [
                {
                    "amount": 15704,
                    "pricePerUnit": 13.0,
                    "orders": 1
                },
                {
                    "amount": 664,
                    "pricePerUnit": 14.5,
                    "orders": 1
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1024,
                    "pricePerUnit": 14.6,
                    "orders": 1
                }
            ],
            "quick_status": {
                "productId": "BROWN_MUSHROOM",
                "sellPrice": 11.334521089630933,
                "sellVolume": 1131729,
                "sellMovingWeek": 10721858,
                "sellOrders": 42,
                "buyPrice": 14.346240421455938,
                "buyVolume": 1698662,
                "buyMovingWeek": 4432754,
                "buyOrders": 785
            }
        },
```

This is the full code:

```js
const axios = require("axios").default;

async function bazaar() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=xxxxxxx"
    );

    var newJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));

    var array = [];
    for (i in newJson.products) {

        var productName = newJson.products[i].product_id
        var sellSummary = newJson.products[i].sell_summary[0].pricePerUnit
        var buySummary  = newJson.products[i].buy_summary[0].pricePerUnit
        var mathSummary = buySummary-sellSummary

        array.push(
            productName,
            sellSummary,
            buySummary
        );
      
    }

    console.log(newJson);
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
}
```

What I was trying to do was:
Getting the `product_id`, `sell_summary[0].pricePerUnit` and `buy_summary[0].pricePerUnit`

When I tried accessing `product_id`, `sell_summary[0]`, `buy_summary[0]`

I got something like this:

```
  'ENCHANTED_RAW_SALMON',
  { amount: 52447, pricePerUnit: 1570.6, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 493, pricePerUnit: 1600.9, orders: 1 },
  'ENCHANTED_GLISTERING_MELON',
  { amount: 112, pricePerUnit: 12001.4, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 1, pricePerUnit: 15578.1, orders: 1 },
  'PRISMARINE_SHARD',
  { amount: 65682, pricePerUnit: 1.5, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 3212, pricePerUnit: 3.8, orders: 1 },
  'ENCHANTED_EMERALD',
  { amount: 38617, pricePerUnit: 971.8, orders: 2 },
  { amount: 66, pricePerUnit: 1012.1, orders: 1 },
  'PROTECTOR_FRAGMENT',
  { amount: 9, pricePerUnit: 2400.3, orders: 1 },
  { amount: 4, pricePerUnit: 2793.2, orders: 1 },
```

That's why I tried accessing `pricePerUnit`on each sell & buy_summary

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little better? is `newJson` the array of the `Layout`? can you show the `newJson` array?

Comment: The newJson:
```
    SNOW_BLOCK: {
      product_id: 'SNOW_BLOCK',
      sell_summary: [Array],
      buy_summary: [Array],
      quick_status: [Object]
    },
```

the `layout` was just after accessing sell_summary / buy_summary which has the pricePerUnit in it but I can't access it


So what I was doing is accessing sell/buy_summary to get access to pricePerUnit but it seems like I can't access it

Comment: Don't use the comment sections, but [edit] to add further details to your question.

Comment: What is newJSON ? Also it is not easy to understand the layout bit. What is layout here

Comment: If `newJson.products[i].sell_summary[0].pricePerUnit` or `newJson.products[i].buy_summary[0].pricePerUnit` results in that error, then either one of those arrays has not elements, or `undefined` as first element.

Comment: One of your array is empty at some point. Check the data. Post is here if needed

Comment: For such an error you first should use a debugger, configure it so that it will break on exceptions, and then check the contents of the object you want to read in the debugger.

Comment: Edited :)
Also yes it's undefined but I don't understand why that's the case (see my edit)

Comment: i is defined as a product, and you're indexing through the array with it, as well as referencing the entire list.  So instead of newJson.products[i].field, wouldn't it be i.field?

Comment: For the data you show the error won't appear. But some of the products in the complete result have an empty array for `sell_summary`.

Comment: @G-Force a `for - in` loop iterates over the properties. So `newJson.products[i]` is correct.

Comment: Tried just using i and it gives me the "name" not the product_id. If I try to do something like i.product_id it already tells me it's undefined, same for everything else

Comment: @t.niese oh well that actually could be the case, let me try to fix it

//edit: that is sadly not the case... tried getting the `pricePerUnit` from one that I know it has it but even then it's still undefined

Comment: @t.niese, if that's the case, then isn't the property after the [i] redundant?

Comment: @Lync it is definitely the case there are - at the time of writing that comment - two products that have an empty `sell_summary` and two that have an empty `buy_summary`.

Comment: @G-Force no `products` is an **object** that (as shown in the question) has this format `"products": { "BROWN_MUSHROOM": { "product_id": "BROWN_MUSHROOM",`. So `i` would e.g. have the value `BROWN_MUSHROOM`, so `products['BROWN_MUSHROOM'].product_id`. (But even if it would be an array it would be the same situation, `for-in` iterates over the property names over their value).

Comment: @t.niese yes yes of course.  I missed the outside {, and threw me off a layer.  thanks :)

Comment: @t.niese hmm well if I'm being honest I'm not entirely sure on what to do about it... since I don't just wanna fill it with 0's. Guess there must be a way to remove empty ones

Comment: Well you need to know what you want to do if either `buy_summary` or `sell_summary` has no elements. How should we know that.

Comment: Well if they have no elements, just remove them I guess? It's not like I could read anything from them anyways.

Comment: I was trying to use `filter` but from the looks of it none of `pricePerUnit` have anything in it even tho it still get's displayed if I call `buy_summary` or `sell_summary`. So it seems like I'm doing something else wrong, right? @t.niese

Comment: @Lysec I'm sorry you seem to lack fundamental knowledge about how to debug and interpret errors. That makes it hard to nearly impossible to help you with your question. There are - at the time of writing -  `906` products that have at least one element for both `buy_summary` and `sell_summary` with a value for `pricePerUnit`, and two products have at least for `buy_summary` and `sell_summary` no elements.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I do know that I have a lot of issues with understanding anything. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to find my own way to fixing issues but I sadly don't really see a way to do it currently. I might have to add that I'm somewhat new to nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that hopefully helps you to track down your problem.
`try-catch` block is moved into the for loop so that errors that happen with one product won't break the loop.

Changed `var newJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));' to` var newJson = res.data;' because I don't see the purpose of cloning the object.

```js
async function bazaar() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=xxxxxxx"
    );

    var newJson = res.data;

    var array = [];
    for (i in newJson.products) {
      try {

            var productName = newJson.products[i].product_id
            var sellSummary = newJson.products[i].sell_summary[0].pricePerUnit
            var buySummary  = newJson.products[i].buy_summary[0].pricePerUnit
            var mathSummary = buySummary-sellSummary

            array.push(
                productName,
                sellSummary,
                buySummary
            );
      } catch (error) {
         console.log('problem reading product '+i, error.message)
      }
      
    }
    console.dir(array)

}

bazaar()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.4/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh my god, now I actually feel stupid. I probably was just overthinking it once again... thank you a lot @t.niese